# How to pass a selected/ onPress item from the FlatList to another function?

Tags: react-native

I tried to use this blogpost  [How to use the FlatList Component — React Native Basics by Spencer Carli](https://medium.com/react-native-development/how-to-use-the-flatlist-component-react-native-basics-92c482816fe6)  to replace my ListView with FlatList, But for some reason Im not able to figure out how to pass the selected item to another function so that I can have it navigate to another view. Here's the code( using expo )

In the onPressFlat function I want to grab the item variable.

Next try: Im trying the code at the medium post itself, I can't get the item upon click. on line no 117 in following code. Im using expo to run this file.

```
import React from 'react';
// import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
// import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, StyleSheet, FlatList, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import { List, ListItem, SearchBar } from "react-native-elements";



export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      loading: false,
      data: [],
      page: 1,
      seed: 1,
      error: null,
      refreshing: false
    };
  }
// https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=1&page=1&results=20`
  componentDidMount() {
    this.makeRemoteRequest();
  }

  makeRemoteRequest = () => {
    const { page, seed } = this.state;
    const url = `https://randomuser.me/api/?seed=${seed}&page=${page}&results=20`;
    this.setState({ loading: true });

    fetch(url)
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: page === 1 ? res.results : [...this.state.data, ...res.results],
          error: res.error || null,
          loading: false,
          refreshing: false
        });
      })
      .catch(error => {
        this.setState({ error, loading: false });
      });
  };

  handleRefresh = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: 1,
        seed: this.state.seed + 1,
        refreshing: true
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  handleLoadMore = () => {
    this.setState(
      {
        page: this.state.page + 1
      },
      () => {
        this.makeRemoteRequest();
      }
    );
  };

  renderSeparator = () => {
    return (
      <View
        style={{
          height: 1,
          width: "86%",
          backgroundColor: "#CED0CE",
          marginLeft: "14%"
        }}
      />
    );
  };

  renderHeader = () => {
    return <SearchBar placeholder="Type Here..." lightTheme round />;
  };

  renderFooter = () => {
    if (!this.state.loading) return null;

    return (
      <View
        style={{
          paddingVertical: 20,
          borderTopWidth: 1,
          borderColor: "#CED0CE"
        }}
      >
        <ActivityIndicator animating size="large" />
      </View>
    );
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <List containerStyle={{ borderTopWidth: 0, borderBottomWidth: 0 }}>
        <FlatList
          data={this.state.data}
          renderItem={({ item }) => (
            <ListItem
              roundAvatar
              title={`${item.name.first} ${item.name.last}`}
              subtitle={item.email}
              avatar={{ uri: item.picture.thumbnail }}
              containerStyle={{ borderBottomWidth: 0 }}
              onPress={(item)=>{
                  console.log('117- onPress clicked log item =', item );
                  // this._onPressFlat(item)
                }}
            />
          )}
          keyExtractor={item => item.email}
          ItemSeparatorComponent={this.renderSeparator}
          ListHeaderComponent={this.renderHeader}
          ListFooterComponent={this.renderFooter}
          onRefresh={this.handleRefresh}
          refreshing={this.state.refreshing}
          onEndReached={this.handleLoadMore}
          onEndReachedThreshold={50}
        />
      </List>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fff',
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

Comment: I have tried this Blog post, It should work. Did you try  onPress like this?  onPress={(item)=>this._onPressFlat(item)}

Comment: @Dinith  I tried that and the whole thing hangs. Im using Expo

Comment: Can you share the full code?

Comment: @DinithMinura I've pasted the full code above, to run it command is : expo start